# Ошибка LNK1104 не удается открыть файл "opengl32.lib glut32.lib glu32.lib"

Tags: visual-studio, glut, компоновщик

Windows 10, 64 битная, Visual studio 14, c++. Библиотеки закинул в "...\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib", header в "...\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include", dll в "C:\Windows\SysWOW64". В компоновщике прописал "opengl32.lib glut32.lib glu32.lib". Visual studio с правами администратора.

Comment: Ошибка говорит о том, что студия не может найти lib-файлы там, где она их ищет.

Comment: Закинь в папку проекта.

Comment: закинул, в компоновщике указал путь к ним. Ошибка осталась.